# Test.startTest() not working as desired

Tags: soql, governorlimits

I came across a very weird issue. In my test method, I'm running into a too many soql queries exception before even setting up my test data for a use case. So, I've moved Test.startTest() little bit upwards before the line causing 101th query hoping Test.startTest() method will reset the limits. Surprisingly, it was still running into the same too many soql exceptions. **Test.startTest() did not reset the limits**. So, I put a debug log to get total soql queries before the line that's causing the error. This time, with the debug, it doesn't throw any error. If I remove the debug, then it will run into too many soql queries.
So, what i understood is, **using both Test.startTest() and limits.getQueries() in debug, the reset works**.

My code:

```
insert somList;//This is where I hit my 100th query. So the next query will be 101th.
System.debug(logginglevel.error, '***SOQL Count 1***'+limits.getQueries());//The debug prints 100.
Test.startTest();
//This debug is doing magic. If I put the debug, queries count resets. Otherwise it doesn't.
System.debug(logginglevel.error, '***SOQL Count 2***'+limits.getQueries());
//This would be the 101th query if there is no startTest() above.
List<Account> listAcnts= [SELECT ID, Name FROM Account WHERE xxxxx];
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are going to have to post more code than that along with the debug log output for the specific error giving the class and line number and stack trace

Comment: Eric, the Error is: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101 and Stack Trace: line 124, column 1, in my aboe code, the line would be (List<Account> listAcnts= [SELECT ID, Name FROM Account WHERE xxxxx];). That's pretty standard error. I've already mentioned the debug output in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: What triggers do you have on the sObject type associated with `somList`? There are likely bulkification issues there if you get to 100 SOQL queries after inserting them.

Comment: Daniel, what I did not understand in this issue is, why the existence of a debug is causing the error to go away. If I remove the debug with limits.getQueries(), the error appears.

Comment: Avinash, while debugging SOQL limit errors the line at which you receive the error holds very little importance compared to the statements executed prior to it since they are consuming you 100 queries. The debug line is not doing the _magic_ ,it is because of start test method. For debugging yourself, you can set a debug log, run the test class. Then open the log and in your browser,press control+F. Search for SELECT word. See how many times is that appearing and what is the query that is running multiple times. The find the class which contains that query and bulkify if necessary.

Comment: Start test method resets the limit. It is helpful if you code has asynchronous executions or if you have lots of test data to be inserted prior to your actual testing. Please see the documentation for Test class in Salesforce. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: @AvinashN - Without the exact stack trace and more code to go by you are not going to get a direct answer. You said that it occurs before you even set up the data so that code is important. Without the information requested this question will most likely be closed

Comment: I think, I failed to explain clearly. A simple debug statement is making all the difference. That is all I wanted to say. The debug is: System.debug(logginglevel.error, '***SOQL Count***'+limits.getQueries()); If I put this debug, then there will be no 101 SOQL error, if I don't put the debug, I get this error. I know, this sounds crazy...but that is what happened to me. I came to know that this is known issue and listed on salesforce developer community. Please see this link: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5R5AAK

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your time. I've debugged all that and even know exactly where my 100th soql query. I wanted to say that Test.startTest() is not working as desired and I found my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can totally understand how everyone thinks if I say a debug statement is helping to reset the limits. But that is what just happened.

Final answer is...**This is a known issue**. The Test.startTest() method is not working as desired. Please go through the below link. Thanks everyone, for your time.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5R5AAK